# What do you call a wealthy person who doesn't care about how the poor feel and live?

Tags: single-word-requests

In Persian a wealthy person with no hardships who is unfeeling and cruel to the poor is known as a:

> مرفه بیدرد - someone who is **featherbedded** and can't ever understand the unprivileged's feeling and pain.

Is there a similar word in English which denotes a filthy rich class who shows no sympathy toward the poor?

Example:

> In a stagflation or economic crisis ______ never understand how the middle class feel when they're trying not to slide down to the line of poverty, and just they're just trying to make ends meet.

Comment: There are a number of idioms about wealth. 'born with a silver spoon in their mouth' is close to the Persian but is not as much about lacking sympathy about the poor but about having nothing to worry about (like what poor people would have to).

Comment: "A wealthy person"

Comment: The White House administration? In the UK, they might be referred to as the filthy rich,  snobs, elitists, Conservatists, Daily Mail readers... out of touch...

Answer (score 2):

A recent coinage for that (circa 2011) in the US is "the one percent" or "the 1%".

See this wikipedia article about [the Occupy movement and its slogan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We_are_the_99%25) "We are the 99%".

Comment: Hmmm.... The 1% refers to anyone who is rich, regardless of whether they care about the poor or not. Some people who are definitely part of the 1% (for example Bill Gates) donate a lot to charity, so it's hard to say they don't care.

Comment: Thx for the contributions but this question still seems unanswered

Answer (score 0):

In many cases I suspect the mere fact of a person's wealth is enough to imply a disconnect from the poor.

An option which implies both wealth and a lack of consideration for the poor (albeit, a word that applies to an individual instead of a whole class of people) would be "scrooge", from the character Scrooge in *A Christmas Carol*.